# How should liquid/jekyll logic tags be used?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I explain myself,
Here a code example I tried:

```
{% assign a=1 %}
{% if a==1 %}
<h1>'a' is equal to one!</h1>
{% else %}
<h1> 'a' is NOT equal to one!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

The output is:

> 'a' is NOT equal to one!

**What's going on?**

Comment: Can you approve @tkeber answer, please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keep some space around the == operator:

```
{% if a == 1 %}
```